# Increment MySQL row value based on PHP form submission

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, increment

I have a simple form, and a MySQL table set up.

All I am trying to do is every time the form is submitted add 1 onto the selected row amount.

Table is as simple as:

```
    answer | amount
------------------------
    Yes    | 5
    No     | 12
    Maybe  | 1
```

And the form is:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Is this a cool pie chart?:
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"> No<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Maybe"> Maybe<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in submit.php I have the following so far, but doesn't seem to be working

```
 <?php
    $sql = "UPDATE results SET amount= amount + 1 where answer = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $selected_option);   

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $selected_option = $_POST['group1'];
         if ($selected_option == 'Yes') {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          }else if ($selected_option == 'No') {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          } else if ($selected_option == 'Maybe')
             mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
?>
```

So if someone answers yes the amount row for yes will increase to 6 etc etc.

I have managed to call the data and even add it into the Google Visualization API using tutorials, but seem to failing at this part.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Can we see your `submit.php` code?

Comment: what you want a mysql query?

Comment: I have made an edit to include the submit.php code so far, not even sure if i'm on the right path :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you issue the query

```
UPDATE results SET amount = amount + 1
```

you will update the *amount*-value of every line in the table. So you have to specify the row with a `WHERE`-predicate:

```
UPDATE results SET amount = amount + 1 WHERE answer = ?
```

The value for ? should be the posted value of the *group1*-variable. In order to prevent SQL injection do this as a prepared statement ( see http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php )

Comment: I have updated my code as shown above but doesn't actually update the table. Must be something minor now thats stopping it from working :/

Comment: Ok got it working! was purely the brackets wrapped around the amount = amount + 1 that stopped it... don't know why I had that!

Thanks for your help